# Several push notifications being received with iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, notifications, urbanairship.com

I'm working on an app that has **push** **notifications** **enabled**. My app it's using push notifications since day 1 with **parse.com** as the server.

Everything was **working** **fine**, I did several app updates and improvements and I had always receive one notification for each push sent by the server, I've also updated from parse 1.7.2 to 1.12.0 without having issues.

Because parse.com was going to terminate its services, I started the migration from parse to **Urban Airship (using 7.0.2)**.

I did several tests, installing and uninstalling the app on my phone, installing the production version (using parse) and installing the development version (using urban airship), everything was working fine, when **suddenly** and I don't know why, I started **receiving 5 notifications** per push sent by the server. I thought it was a **parse.com** problem because at that time my **iPhone** was running the **production version (with parse)**, but it was not.

When the version **(using Urban Airship)** was just published, I kept receiving 5 notifications.

I'm totally lost here, I don't have any clue why this is happening, at first I thought it was related with the several installs and uninstalls of the app, so I try:

```
1. Disabling notifications.-
2. Deleting the app.-
3. Disabling notifications
3.a. deleting the app
3.b. then changing time and date ahead a couple of days
3.c. then turning off the phone
3.d. turning on again and putting the right date
3.e. restarting the phone
3.f. installing the app
```

None of those worked so far. And I couldn't find anything online about this issue that was clear or solve this issue.

I hope someone could help me.

Extra info:

```
Swift 2
iOS 8.0+
XCode 7
Pushes are sent by a PHP Server
```

**My AppDelegate.swift** (Please notice that I have only included the relevant code, the rest of the code is not related):

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import AirshipKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let config: UAConfig = UAConfig.defaultConfig()
        UAirship.takeOff(config)
        UAirship.push().userPushNotificationsEnabled = true
        UAirship.push().resetBadge()

        // Get the user settings
        let userSettings = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var notify = userSettings.dictionaryForKey("notifications")
        let appReset = userSettings.objectForKey("appResetv200")

        if appReset == nil {
            notify = nil

            userSettings.setObject("done", forKey: "appResetv200")
        }

        if notify == nil {
            let notificationTypes = [
                "notType1" : true,
                "notType2" : true,
                "notType3" : true
            ]

            userSettings.setObject(notificationTypes, forKey: "notifications")

            UAirship.push().addTag("notType1")
            UAirship.push().addTag("notType2")
            UAirship.push().addTag("notType3")
            UAirship.push().updateRegistration()
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me, everything worked fine when I did the tests on my development environment, and now it's a complete mystery why it's failing.

Comment: You mention a pho server, so that is talking to urban airship? Are you maybe registering multiple times with that server and instead of replacing the new Id its adding it as a new one?

Comment: The PHP server just makes a push on those channels. For example: if event 1 happens send to tag notType1, if event 2 happens send to tag notType2, if event 1 and 2 happens, send to notType1 and notType2. If I check the notifications report it says just one push. I'm not seeing nothing weird.

Comment: Ok it seems like a multiple registered issue somewhere which is why I asked

Comment: Yes, but the question is where or why :/ The only thing I do is update the tags in the settings section using addTag, removeTag and after any of those using the updateRegistration() method.

Comment: Did you look at the installations in parse and the channels in UA for dupes?